# Write html code in comments

Tags: comments, html, code, pre

For example i am writing this html code into comment textarea

```
<pre><code class="language-php"><?php echo esc_html( get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), ‘_spp_count’, true ) ); ?></code></pre>
```

But it looks like this:

[image]

Comment: Can you clarify, are you wanting to **embed** that code so that others can view it? Or are you trying to **execute** that code as PHP code?

Comment: Yes i am trying to embed code to show others.